# rolling join and chose only previous values if there are equidistant matches

Tags: r, data.table

I want rolling join with 'nearest', but if there are equidistant matches, I'd like to pick only the exact and previous matches. I'm working with the weights and heights of infants

```
library(data.table)

# height data:
dh <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,3),2), agedays = c(30,70,140,26), ht=51:54) |> setDT()
dh$htdays <- dh$agedays 

# weight data:
dw <- data.frame(id,agedays = c(10,30,50,100,150,25), wt=1:6) |> setDT()


# note that the ht at 30 days is equidistant from the wts at 10 and 50 days

x <- dh[dw, roll = "nearest", on=.(id,agedays)]; x 
x[,let(agediff=agedays-htdays)][]
```

I'd like to have the ht at 30 days match with the wts at 10 and 30 days, but not with the wt at 50 days.  This condition (exact match and precious match) would apply to only equidistant matches.

At first, I thought that I could just use setorder() and unique(), but that won't work if there are wts at 51, 52, and 53 days.  I also thought that I could use rowid(ht) to do this, but I haven't had any luck.

There's probably an easy solution that I don't know.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you share your expected output? Also what is `id` suppose to be in `dw`?

Comment: Glad to learn of [`let`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) which will be in an upcoming `data.table` release.

Comment: @Frank - let() is in the development package.  In the past, when I've come back from a vacation I always forgot if it's := or =: !

Answer (score 1):

You could group by `abs(agedays-htdays)` and if there are many matches, take only the matches where `agedays-htdays<=0`:

```r
library(data.table)
x <- dh[dw, roll = "nearest", on=.(id,agedays)];  
x[,let(agediff=agedays-htdays)]
x[,let(agediffabs=abs(agedays-htdays))]

x[,.SD[.N==1|(agediff<=0)],.(id,agediffabs)]

#>       id agediffabs agedays    ht htdays    wt agediff
#>    <num>      <num>   <num> <int>  <num> <int>   <num>
#> 1:     1         20      10    51     30     1     -20
#> 2:     1          0      30    51     30     2       0
#> 3:     2         74     100    54     26     4      74
#> 4:     2        124     150    54     26     5     124
#> 5:     2          1      25    54     26     6      -1
```

Corrected data with `id` for `dw`:

```
# height data:
dh <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,3),2), agedays = c(30,70,140,26), ht=51:54) |> setDT()
dh$htdays <- dh$agedays 

# weight data:
dw <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3)),agedays = c(10,30,50,100,150,25), wt=1:6) |> setDT()


# note that the ht at 30 days is equidistant from the wts at 10 and 50 days
```

Comment: thanks.  I should have thought about this a little more before I posted.  Can I ask: what does the .N==1 do?  Wouldn't using only the agediff<=0 by itself accomplish the same thing?

Comment: `.N==1` is for single matches where `agediff>0` like row 4